# Group by ID in List object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hi I'm trying to use LINQ to group some data that I got back. Data:

```
[
  {
    "TicketID": 11,
    "Priority": 1,
    "Email": "someemail@asdf.com",        
    "Files": [
      {
        "FileID": 1,
        "FileName": "file1.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "TicketID": 11,
    "Priority": 1,
    "Email": "someemail@asdf.com",        
    "Files": [
      {
        "FileID": 2,
        "FileName": "file2.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "TicketID": 11,
    "Priority": 1,
    "Email": "someemail@asdf.com",        
    "Files": [
      {
        "FileID": 3,
        "FileName": "file3.png"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Is it possible to group like this:

```
[
  {
    "TicketID": 11,
    "Priority": 1,
    "Email": "someemail@asdf.com",        
    "Files": [
      {
        "FileID": 1,
        "FileName": "file1.png"
      },
      {
        "FileID": 2,
        "FileName": "file2.png"
      },
      {
        "FileID": 3,
        "FileName": "file3.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to use LINQ:

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(gb => gb.TicketID).SelectMany(s => s);
```

But it's getting the same output as the original. Maybe someone would know.
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look a [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx) which has plenty of examples of how to use `GroupBy`...

Comment: That's right. You group into groups by TicketID, and then you use SelectMany to flatten out those groups into a single enumeration again. `s` is the `Group` object, which implements `IEnumerable`. What was your goal here? If you just want an enumeration of groups, get rid of `SelectMany`; you already got that with `GroupBy`.

Comment: Can you assume that the `Priority` and `Email` are the same if the `TicketID` is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `TicketID`, `Email` and `Priority` are they keys by which you want to group together your array, then you can do:

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(i => new
{
    i.TicketID,
    i.Priority,
    i.Email
}).Select(g => new Ticket()
{
    TicketID = g.Key.TicketID,
    Email = g.Key.Email,
    Priority = g.Key.Priority,
    Files = g.SelectMany(x => x.Files).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

where `Ticket` is a class representing the JSON in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one TicketID then you can do this (call your data src):

```
var tf = src.First();
var ans = new { TicketID = tf.TicketID, Priority = tf.Priority, Email = tf.Email,
    Files = src.SelectMany(t => t.Files).ToArray() };
```

If you want to handle multiple TicketIDs in your answer and combine them by TicketID, then like this:

```
var ans = src.GroupBy(t => t.TicketID).Select(
    gp => new { GP = gp, GPF = gp.First() }).Select(
        gpf => new { TickedID=gpf.GPF.TicketID, Priority = gpf.GPF.Priority,
                     Email = gpf.GPF.Email,
                     Files = gpf.GP.SelectMany(gp => gp.Files).ToArray() }).ToArray();
```

The first Select is just to simulate a Let to prevent repeating gp.First() for the duplicated fields. Query syntax would look like:

```
var ans = from t in src 
          group t by t.TicketID into gp
          let gpf = gp.First()
          select new { TicketID = gpf.TicketID, Priority = gpf.Priority, Email = gpf.Email,
                       Files = gp.SelectMany(gp => gp.Files).ToArray() };
```